# Problem using AmCharts comparison callback in Angular 11 application

Tags: angular, amcharts5

I am using the AmCharts 5 stockchart in an angular 11 application.

I am loading the chart with data retrieved from the server but I would like to be able to compare the price chart with another stock.

Based upon the examples here ([here](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/stock/toolbar/comparison-control/#Dynamic_list)) I have implemented the following callback:

```
 const comparisonControl = am5stock.ComparisonControl.new(root, {
            stockChart: stockChart,
            searchable: true,
            searchCallback: function(query) {
                return that._company.getListOfCompanies(query)
                    .pipe(takeWhile(x => that.alive))
                    .subscribe((cos: ICompanySearchResults) => {
                        const filteredCompanies = cos.data;
                        const list = [];
                        for (const item of filteredCompanies) {
                            list.push({label: item.name, subLabel: item.ticker, id: item.cik});
                        }
                        return items;
                    });
   }
```

I have checked that the call is indeed being made and that data is being returned and that the items array is being correctly generated. But nothing get popped up so I assume that it is an issue somehow with the Promise being returned.

Any help gratefully received !

Answer (score 0):

And as usual 5 minutes after posting this question I found the answer !

```
const promise = that._company.getListOfCompanies(query, false, 'ticker', false).toPromise();

                return promise.then(
                    (response: any) => {
                        // Success callback
                        const list = [];
                        for (const item of response.data) {
                            list.push({label: item.name, subLabel: item.ticker, id: item.cik});
                        }
                        return list;
                    },
                    (error: any) => {
                        // Error callback
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                );
```

So I needed to convert the http call to a promise and then return that with the async processing in the then.